# How to Remove duplicate rows having minimal set of information?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation,
My MySQL table (company) contains duplicate records,i.e.,it has repeated companies, some records have values in most columns and some don't have. So I want to remove the duplicate companies having minimal set of information. Guys any ideas?

```
Id Company_name column column2 column3 column4    
-------------------------------------------------
1  A                   xyz 
2  B            pqr    abc      tcv    aaa 
3  A            bnm    xyz      ccc     
4  A            bnm    xyz         
5  B                                   aaa
```

I need to get my table as follows

```
Id Company_name column column2 column3 column4    
-------------------------------------------------    
2  B            pqr    abc      tcv    aaa 
3  A            bnm    xyz      ccc
```

Comment: Get me some more information like which columns can have duplicate values

Comment: Every column can have duplicate values, I need to preserve only one record with which have values in most number of columns.

Comment: If you find a really good algorithm that works a charm, you just made a million dollars. This is one of those tasks that just plain sucks, The easiest way is to enforce strict data input in the first place, but you probably know that now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a php method to do this work, and manually you will retrieve all the record grouped by the column by what you want to reduce the repetitive rows. In above case you are considering for the `Company_name` column. But there is possibility that it may have some different value on other columns but not in the Company_name column. This may create ambiguity in understanding that how it will the algorithm will treat such type of row.
But it will be good practice that before inserting the values, the information must be checked so no repetition occurs. But in the case when you already have such records,following query may help.

```
DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE (Company_name, column) 
NOT IN 
(
  SELECT  Company_name, column FROM 
  (
    SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, column FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY Company_name
  ) 
  X
);
```

This is for deleting the duplicate values for one column, you can make with combination of multiple query to reduce the duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get a "score" of each row and base the decision on that. Here is a quick example that shows where to start.

```
SELECT id, 
       name,  
       length(concat_ws('', col1, col2, col3, col4)) AS score 
  FROM company
 ORDER BY score DESC;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5368f/6)

Comment: You should probably have another function than concat_ws and length, perhaps a sum of isnull(col1) and so on. But you get the idea.